# AWS WorkSpaces With Windows 10

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-workspaces

Hi I would like to know if AWS WorkSpaces offers Windows 10?

When I create a Windows 10 workspace, and it is launched, the settings sections says it is running Windows Server 2016.

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon WorkSpaces uses the [Windows 10 desktop experience](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/11/amazon-workspaces-introduces-windows-10-desktop-experience/) to give Windows 10-like experience, but it is actually running on Windows 2016 underneath.

This is a normal service provided by Microsoft. Just pretend it is Windows 10 and it will mostly work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

AWS offers a windows server os with desktop experience because of the Microsoft licensing.

In case you've a large volume of WorkSpaces and want to use BYOL you can upload a real Windows 10 image.

From: [Bring Your Own Windows Desktop Licenses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/byol-windows-images.html)

> If your licensing agreement with Microsoft allows it, you can use your Windows 10 Enterprise or Windows 10 Pro desktop licenses for your WorkSpaces. To do this, you must Bring Your Own License (BYOL) and provide a Windows 10 license that meets the following requirements. To stay compliant with Microsoft licensing terms, AWS runs your BYOL WorkSpaces on hardware that is dedicated to you in the AWS Cloud.